# Cyber-duck Installation failed, reverting in Laravel-8

Tags: laravel

I had earlier installed maatwebsite/excel-3.1, and it was okay. I have Laravel-8 and PHP-7.3 and I am trying to install cyber-duck:

```
composer require cyber-duck/laravel-excel
```

But I got this error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - Root composer.json requires cyber-duck/laravel-excel ^2.1 -> >satisfiable by cyber-duck/laravel-excel[2.1.0].
> - cyber-duck/laravel-excel 2.1.0 requires illuminate/database >^6.0.0|^7.0.0 -> found illuminate/database[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, >..., 7.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with >another require.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as release versions of `cyber-duck/laravel-excel` are concerned, the latest version of the package (commit: `b98ad4d`) is only supporting Laravel `version 7.x`.
https://github.com/Cyber-Duck/laravel-excel/releases

So, either you have to downgrade your Laravel version or wait for the latest release version which supports Laravel `version 8.x`.

Comment: @Thanluong - The same error still came up

Comment: Could you please share the output `composer.json`?

Comment: Did you get the same error when you use `composer update`?

Comment: @Thanluong - Okay. Thanks